# how can I make a text entry field

Tags: php, javascript

How can I make a text entry field that takes the input characters and displays it in another place, character by character as a the typest type them!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="textField" />
<br />
<span id="textOutput"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var input = document.getElementById("textField");
    var output = document.getElementById("textOutput");

    // sorry, it's better to use "onkeyup" event
    // to avoid the problem described in a post below
    input.onkeyup = function(){
        output.innerText = input.value;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start by having a look at the sourcecode of the edit fields in this site.
The preview is updated as you type.